# Automatically created (and ascendingly sorted) footnotes list in a dedicated chapter with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I desire to use an automatically created (and ascendingly sorted) footnotes list in a dedicated chapter with vanilla JavaScript:

- In client mode, footnote text from HTML source code should appear under Footnotes chapter automatically numbered and sorted ascending.
- Numbers representing number of footnote should appear super to each paragraph that has a footnote (replacing its actual text).

---

I have created the following HTML document.
Source code:

```
<div id="main_chapter_region">
    <h1 id="main_chapter_heading">Main chapter</h2>
    <p>Some paragraph text<span class="footnote"><sup>Some footnote text</sup></span></p>
    <p>Some paragraph text<span class="footnote"><sup>Some footnote text</sup></span></p>
</div>

<div id="footnotes_chapter_region">
    <h2 id="footnotes_chapter_heading">Footnotes chapter</h2>
    <ol id="footnotes_list">
        <!-- Automatically created and sorted list items come here; -->
    </ol>
</div>
```

Expected display mode:

## Main chapter

Paragraph<sup>1</sup>
Paragraph<sup>2</sup>

## Footnotes chapter

1. Some footnote text (as inserted in HTML source code)
2. Some footnote text (as inserted in HTML source code)

---

I understand I need JavaScript to do these steps:

**1)** Copywrite footnote text inside `<span><sup>` to `<ol>` that will hold it.
**2)** Replace recently copywrited footnote with a number respective to `<li>` in `<ol>`.
**3)** Repeat the process for all `<span><sup>` in `#main_chapter_region"`.

What can be a vanilla JavaScript approach to suffice this behavior?
I tried to search for some "cookbook recipe" to learn the logic of a generally similar or identical mechanism but found nothing; not even one session in StackOverflow or similar site. I ask anyone who have such an example to gracefully share as an answer.

Comment: You will need to learn about the [DOM APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). There is no cookbook recipe, it's just finding, manipulating and moving elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `createElement` and `appendChild` methods for the first step. Iteration (step 3) can be done with `querySelectorAll` and a chained `forEach`. This will also give you the sequence number which you can use for knowing the footnote number (step 2).

```js
const list = document.querySelector("#footnotes_list");
document.querySelectorAll(".footnote>sup").forEach((footnote, i) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.append(...footnote.childNodes); // move content
    list.appendChild(li);
    footnote.textContent = i+1;
});
```

```html
<div id="main_chapter_region">
    <h1 id="main_chapter_heading">Main chapter</h2>
    <p>Some paragraph text<span class="footnote"><sup>Some <b>bold</b> footnote text</sup></span></p>
    <p>Some paragraph text<span class="footnote"><sup>Other <i>footnote text</i></sup></span></p>
</div>

<div id="footnotes_chapter_region">
    <h2 id="footnotes_chapter_heading">Footnotes chapter</h2>
    <ol id="footnotes_list">
        <!-- Automatically created and sorted list items come here; -->
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of copying the html, I'd do `while (footnote.children.length) li.appendChild(footnote.firstChild);`.

Comment: Indeed, with the advantage that it preserves existing references like event handlers.