# MediaWiki fails executing JavaScript which gets executed fine in browser console

Tags: javascript, html, global, mediawiki, wiki

The following global JavaScript code is the only JavaScript code I use in my entire all-core, Hebrew, MediaWiki 1.33.0 website:

```
/* כל הסקריפטים הנכתבים כאן ייטענו עבור כל המשתמשים בכל טעינת עמוד. */

const list = document.querySelector("#footnotes_list");
document.querySelectorAll(".footnote>sup").forEach((footnote, i) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.append(...footnote.childNodes); // move content
    list.appendChild(li);
    footnote.textContent = i+1;
});
```

### Related templates

The above JavaScript code is related to the following two templates.
The following Hebrew template names mean "footnote" and "footnotes" respectively:

#### תבנית:הערה

```
<p><span class="footnote"><sup>{{{1}}}</sup></span></p><noinclude>
[[קטגוריה:תבניות עריכה]]
</noinclude>
```

#### תבנית:הערות שוליים

```
<ol id="footnotes_list"></ol><noinclude>
[[קטגוריה:תבניות עריכה]]
</noinclude>
```

### Purpose

This HTML-WIKI-JavaScript combo serves as potential substitute to common references extensions as it allows  each footnote to appear sorted in a footnotes section.
I think it should be useful for people desiring to avoid installing any extensions or skins from various reasons such as the desire to reduce PHP complexity, minimalism philosophy, personal comfortability and possibly more.

### My problem

If I try to execute the JavaScript code from browser console it works fine --- Every footnote inserted to article body appears sorted (respective) under the "footnotes" `ol` chapter.

Yet, if I try to execute that JavaScript code from `https://example.com//index.php?title=מדיה_ויקי:Common.js`, it doesn't work; clearing Chrome cache with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> didn't help.

### My question

What causes MediaWiki to fail running the JavaScript code and how could that be fixed?

---

<sub>Side note: credit goes to user:trincot for [developing the utilized JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56921811/11744452).</sub>

Comment: An anonymous user in MW community said: `MW validates user scripts as ES3, so you can't use modern syntax features like const or array spreading`.

Comment: Indeed, this will break the minifier. You should see an error message on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that MediaWiki's latest release for now (1.33.0) allegedly [can only execute ES3](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:V60dbbakdlwuw8v7).

[This session - question and accepted answer details more and include a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638871/es6-to-es3-translation-for-mediawiki-foreach-method-and-spreading-operator).