# ES6 to ES3 translation for MediaWiki (foreach() method and spreading operator)

Tags: javascript

I desire to execute the following tested, working in console, ES6 code through MediaWiki as [described in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638079/mediawiki-fails-executing-javascript-which-gets-executed-fine-in-browser-console),

but it fails being executed through MediaWiki as its latest release for now (1.33.0) allegedly [can only execute ES3](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:V60dbbakdlwuw8v7):

```
const list = document.querySelector("#footnotes_list");
document.querySelectorAll(".footnote>sup").forEach((footnote, i) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.append(...footnote.childNodes); // move content
    list.appendChild(li);
    footnote.textContent = i+1;
});
```

I assume `const` is okay to become `var`;
I read in W3schools that `forEach()` is ES5 but AFAICR I can replace this with `for` loop.

I miss what could replace array spreading via spread operator (`...`) in ES3.
Google search for "array spreading ES3" (without quote marks) brings no example on how to spread an array in ES3 (maybe the terminology is different?).

If possible within the limitations of ES3, how will you do array spreading with it?

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` is ES5, but `NodeList.prototype.forEach` (`document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, not an array) is a browser API and isn’t related to a specific JavaScript version. The concept of calling a method is valid ES3, though, so if you only need your code to parse as ES3 and not actually be compatible with old engines, it should be fine regardless.

Comment: For old browsers, I guess you would need `NodeList.prototype.forEach` and `Element.append` polyfills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, ["babelified" here](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDAJiYBXAtgUzCgDoBHbfAJwE8BlfOfYKESgCgCIBiAMxBChgB-CAH1E0DgEoA3AChMOAkTIUa9Rs1YBBOHE7E-AoVHwA-CNgAO0w6wCiAQ2AALNmyODhAGhgIpqGYwAN5yMOEwoJCwiKgYWHiEJMCU-I6m9ozKUJyI0vIR8AjEjlZWhOhsxNWeJvjErghw6AByIOgisjAA9N0wuCAAbviR4KZEYRESJKXlYOgAwi5NlYiyk-G1wsSmAB5QC2NJcQgA1ACM8gC-skA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.5.5&externalPlugins=):

```
"use strict";

function _toConsumableArray(arr) { return _arrayWithoutHoles(arr) || _iterableToArray(arr) || _nonIterableSpread(); }

function _nonIterableSpread() { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"); }

function _iterableToArray(iter) { if (Symbol.iterator in Object(iter) || Object.prototype.toString.call(iter) === "[object Arguments]") return Array.from(iter); }

function _arrayWithoutHoles(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) { for (var i = 0, arr2 = new Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) { arr2[i] = arr[i]; } return arr2; } }

var list = document.querySelector("#footnotes_list");
document.querySelectorAll(".footnote>sup").forEach(function (footnote, i) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.append.apply(li, _toConsumableArray(footnote.childNodes)); // move content

  list.appendChild(li);
  footnote.textContent = i + 1;
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. I upvoted. Do you think I can improve the question somehow? Thank you anyway.

Comment: @ShadowyShade Your question is broad. The goal of Stack Overflow is to build a library of questions and answers that future visitors can use. Future visitors are very unlikely to try exactly the same as you do, so the question wont be of any value to the site. If you would make your question very specific (like "how can you use `...footnote.childNodes` in ES5"), then your question might be beneficial to others as well. (But the above example is likely already answered on the site somewhere.) (Not my downvote though.)