# How to automatically create local href links?

Tags: javascript, client, href, dom-events, mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki 1.33.0 website in which some articles contain footnotes. My problem is that these footnotes aren't locally linked (there is no link from footnote number to "footnotes" or "references" chapter).

I create article footnotes by the following *Wiki syntax* templates and corresponding *JavaScript* codeblock:

### 1. Footnotes template

```
<includeonly><ol id="footnotes_list"></ol></includeonly><noinclude>

[[קטגוריה:תבניות]]
</noinclude>
```

### 2. Footnote template

```
<includeonly><span dir="rtl" class="footnote"><sup class="footnote_inner">{{{1}}}</sup></span></includeonly><noinclude>

[[קטגוריה:תבניות]]
</noinclude>
```

### 3. Corresponding JavaScript

```
const list = document.querySelector("#footnotes_list");
document.querySelectorAll(".footnote>sup").forEach((footnote, i) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.append(...footnote.childNodes); // move content
    list.appendChild(li);
    footnote.textContent = i+1;
});
```

<sub>[Credit for `user:trincot` for developing that code;](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56921811/11744452)</sub>

---

### Footnoted-article example:

```
תוכן{{הערה|תוכן ההערה}}

==Footnotes Chapter==
{{הערות שוליים}}
```

> ### My article
>
> <sup>1</sup>תוכן
>
> #### Footnotes chapter
>
> 1. תוכן ההערה

PHP execution of the above three code blocks allows such parsing and rendering of footnotes.

---

### My problem

Footnotes created by the above code doesn't contain local `href` attributes and therefore, footnote numbers aren't clickable (as they are in English Wikipedia).

I desire footnote numbers to be clickable and that clicking on them will lead a user to their corresponding footnote.

### Note

To **manually** create local `href` link I would do the following (clicking the X leads to Y) but I don't know how to create this **automatically**:

```html
<a href="#my_manual_href">X</a>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<h2 id="my_manual_href">Y</h2>
```

### My question

How to automatically create local `href` links?

Comment: If some JavaScript ninja agrees to tweet this --- wow, that will make me happy !

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to give each li item an id as follows:

```
const list = document.querySelector("#footnotes_list");
document.querySelectorAll(".footnote>sup").forEach((footnote, i) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.id = `footnote-${i}`
    li.append(...footnote.childNodes); // move content
    list.appendChild(li);
    footnote.textContent = i+1;
});
```

And then adding a href attribute to the '[1]' element **in your article**.

Assuming you insert the footnote links by code, adding an `href` attribute could look as follows:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".footnote-link").forEach((element, i) => {
    element.href = `#footnote-${i}`;
});
```

Comment: Hello Sophia, thank you, I have updated the question with an example for an articles core content for having a text with a footnote, and a footnotes chapter. Please review the `Example` chapter in my question; although it is in Hebrew, the pattern in the same as in English wiki besides the RTL manner.

Comment: Hello @ShadowyShade, thank you for adding the example. However, I am still missing some crucial information. You show your input and how the article finally looks (the yellow box), but I am missing the template or code that converts your input to the article as in the yellow box. For instance, the article is captioned with "My article" and contains the "[1]" characters, but I don't see a template or code that inserts these pieces of text.

Comment: As far as I understand, the PHP execution of `1. Footnotes template`, `2. Footnote template` and `3. Corresponding JavaScript` together, when parsing and rendering the webpage that contains `תוכן{{הערה|תוכן ההערה}}` **causes** `תוכן ההערה` to but transferred to `Footnotes chapter` and replaced with a `[1]` in the main article text area (that is, all text above `Footnotes chapter`).

Comment: @ShadowyShade do you perhaps have the php code that you describe? Because `1. Footnotes template` and `2. Footnote template` contain no php, only html.

Comment: Sophia, `2. Footnote template` also contains `{{{1}}}` wiki syntax which allows template calls with one or more arguments (such as `{{הערה|תוכן ההערה}}`). Beyond that, I never studied the MediaWiki PHP source code for this → I just use this functionality as is since about 2010, I guess.

Comment: Hello Sophia, I was glad to give you the bounty; if after everything I wrote you got a clearer picture of the circumstances I work under (I'm not a PHP developer BTW), you are welcome to edit the answer accordingly. I thank you anyway for your time on this so far and for your graceful replies here.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowyShade! I'm sorry your problem is not yet resolved. I don't have specific expertise with the MediaWiki tool you are using, but I know there has to be some 'behind-the-scenes' logic that converts the input you provide to the article. However, seeing this code is crucial for adding the feature you request, because it requires some alteration of the elements and attributes that are generated by this code. Perhaps it would be a solution to contact the support staff of this tool and ask them for help?

Comment: @Sophia the community's solution is installing a PHP extension that does almost all of what I already get with JS, by PHP --- which I don't want to. I don't recognize a reason why there shouldn't be a pure JavaScript solution, which I believe has to do with changing `user:trincot`'s code a bit; I might figure out something about this in the future, until then, in my personal website, article footnotes will not be clicked in a local `href` fashion, sadly.